# Concatenate elements from multiple XML files

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I need to open and parse several XML files, keeping the data in memory, and then sort the result.

The script is not finished because I don't know how keep the information in a hash or a variable, that's why I need your help.

#### Perl code

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use POSIX;
use XML::LibXML;

print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime), "\n";

my $DIR = "/totest/";

# Looking for XML files
opendir(DIR, $DIR);
my @SEARCH = grep(/^XML-[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}.FR.*.FORTESTING.xml$/, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

my ($product, $series, $voditem, $episode) = ("", "", "", "");

# If data file so
if ( scalar(@SEARCH) ) {

    foreach ( @SEARCH ) {

        my $filename = $DIR . $_;
        my $doc      = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

        $product = $doc->getDocumentElement->findnodes("/ScheduleProvider/Product")->[0]->toString, "\n";
        $series  = $doc->getDocumentElement->findnodes("/ScheduleProvider/Series"->[0]->toString, "\n";
        $episode = $doc->getDocumentElement->findnodes("/ScheduleProvider/Episode")->[0]->toString, "\n";
        $voditem = $doc->getDocumentElement->findnodes("/ScheduleProvider/VodItem")->[0]->toString, "\n";
    }

    print "$series\n";
}
```

#### Desired output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ScheduleProvider id="FRT">
    <Product action="override" type="single">
        <Price currency="EUR">0.00</Price>
        <EpgDescription locale="fr_FR">
            <EpgElement key="Title">NO TITLE</EpgElement>
        </EpgDescription>
    </Product>
    <Product action="override" type="single">
        <Price currency="EUR">0.00</Price>
        <EpgDescription locale="fr_FR">
            <EpgElement key="Title">NO TITLE</EpgElement>
        </EpgDescription>
    </Product>
    <Series id="TS30200026214" action="override">
            <EpgElement key="IsRecordable">0</EpgElement>
    </Series>
    <Series id="TS20200026214" action="override">
            <EpgElement key="IsRecordable">0</EpgElement>
    </Series>
    <Episode action="override" id="TS303687645464" seriesRef="TS30200026214">
        <Media id="TS300687645464"/>
    </Episode>
    <Episode action="override" id="TS203182282260" seriesRef="TS20200026214">
        <Media id="TS200182282260"/>
    </Episode>
    <VodItem action="override" contentRef="TS303687645464" id="TS304687645464">
        <Period year="2017"/>
    </VodItem>
    <VodItem action="override" contentRef="TS203182282260" id="TS204182282260">
        <Period year="2018"/>
    </VodItem>
</ScheduleProvider>
```

#### XML-20170504_060444.FR.FORTESTING.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ScheduleProvider id="FRT">
    <Product action="override" type="single">
        <Price currency="EUR">0.00</Price>
        <EpgDescription locale="fr_FR">
            <EpgElement key="Title">NO TITLE</EpgElement>
        </EpgDescription>
    </Product>
    <Series id="TS30200026214" action="override">
            <EpgElement key="IsRecordable">0</EpgElement>
    </Series>
    <Episode action="override" id="TS303687645464" seriesRef="TS30200026214">
        <Media id="TS300687645464"/>
    </Episode>
    <VodItem action="override" contentRef="TS303687645464" id="TS304687645464">
        <Period year="2017"/>
    </VodItem>
</ScheduleProvider>
```

#### XML-20170505_073915.FR.FORTESTING.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ScheduleProvider id="FRT">
    <Product action="override" type="single">
        <Price currency="EUR">0.00</Price>
        <EpgDescription locale="fr_FR">
            <EpgElement key="Title">NO TITLE</EpgElement>
        </EpgDescription>
    </Product>
    <Series id="TS20200026214" action="override">
            <EpgElement key="IsRecordable">0</EpgElement>
    </Series>
    <Episode action="override" id="TS203182282260" seriesRef="TS20200026214">
        <Media id="TS200182282260"/>
    </Episode>
    <VodItem action="override" contentRef="TS203182282260" id="TS204182282260">
        <Period year="2018"/>
    </VodItem>
</ScheduleProvider>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to combine elements from multiple XML files into one big XML file?

Comment: Yes that's the point, sorry if it's was not clear enough.

Comment: Do you really want only the first element of the `findnodes` query? That's what the `->[0]` does in `$dom->findnodes(/xpath)->[0]`

Comment: I want everything that is contained into Product, Series, Episode & VodItem. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want everything inside `<ScheduleProvider>`? Are there ever elements that you want to exclude? You say you want the results "in order"; in what order

Comment: Yes you right, everything inside `<ScheduleProvider>` which contain Product, Series, Episode & VodItem. The order is all Product tag first, then, Series, Episode and VodItem at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `if (scalar(@SEARCH))` block, change your code to something like this. It creates a new XML document, and adds the nodes you want from the opened XML docs. I also cleaned up some of the unnecessary verbosity in the XML methods.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

# create new xml doc 
my $new_doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0','utf-8');
my $new_root = $new_doc->createElement('ScheduleProvider');
$new_root->setAttribute('id','FRT');

# for example purposes, let's say the file paths are in the command line arguments
for my $fn (@ARGV) {
    die "file $fn not found" unless -e $fn;

    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $fn);
    my $dom = $doc->getDocumentElement;

    # add the nodes to the new xml doc       
    for my $xpath (qw<//Product //Series //Episode //VodItem>) {
         $new_root->appendChild($_) for $dom->findnodes($xpath);
    }                 
 }

 $new_doc->setDocumentElement($new_root);

 print $new_doc->toString;
```

Comment: I think the XPath should probably be `/*/*` but the OP isn't clear. I recommend using e.g. `/*/Product` instead of `//Product`: there's no point in getting the XML engine to search beyond the second level.

Comment: Thanks @beasy, how can I add a `"\n"` after `<VODContentProvider>` and before `</VODContentProvider>` ? Then the tags are still in the same order how can I have the two `<Product>` first ?

Comment: @Seth: Asking questions like yours makes a mockery of we who try to help on *Stack Overflow*. This is not a chat forum: first of all you should open a new question if you have a new question; and secondly, the new profession of *programming by Stack Overflow* can't be encouraged. We are kind and generous, and if you really seem to be stuck with a problem then we will help. But questions like yours that show some gash code and ask for a solution aren't acceptable: you need to educate yourself to a point where it is at least *possible* that you could solve the problem at hand yourself.

Comment: @Borodin sorry if there is an incomprehension here but there is no mockery at all. I will avoid to ask questions in comments. Regarding my question above I think that `print $new_doc->toString(1);` seems to be right.

Comment: @Seth yes, `toString(1)` should "pretty print" the xml. if you want to group the nodes in a certain order you should probably open a new question as suggested above, since you didn't really specify that in your original post.

Comment: @beasy: Please encourage best practices by *always* using `strict` and `warnings 'all'` in your solutions. And please be careful, or at least consistent, with your spelling. `xml` is spelled `XML` and `openied` is not a word. Remember that every Stack Overflow page is akin to a Wikipedia page, and mistakes are abhorrent.

Comment: @Borodin OK, I've made the suggested corrections. in terms of `strict` and `warnings`, I intended this code snippet to be used within OPs original code, which is already using both. Do you advise copying the whole script?

Comment: @beasy: If you post code that isn't intended to be a stand-alone script then you should write about the presumed context. I think it is always best to post a complete program: as "experts" we are much more able to provide an MCVE *answer* that describes our understanding of the question. Remember that *accuracy* and *precision* are the foundations of our work, and sloppiness in any quarter reflects carelessness everywhere. Software engineering isn't about throwing together some code and waiting for others to find the bugs for us.

Comment: @Borodin Fair enough. Even though the answer was already accepted, I've edited it as suggested.